# How get the HTTP answer from a Service Reference

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap

EDIT : Sorry for my english, it's not my foreign language...

I'm using a service reference in Visual Studio in order to discuss with a webservice. To do that, I integrate the WSDL the owner of the webservice give it to me.

But I'm think the WSDL must be wrong because I see the objects, I see the methods, I can call them but the answer is always 'null'.

But when i use a HTTP sniffer (Fiddler), I see the SOAP answer in the HTTP packet. So, if I must explain properly the problem, it seems the pipe between transport layer and software layer is broken.

So I'm searching a way to retreive directly the HTTP answer from the webservice instance. I don't know if I need to create a custom binding, or use a listener.

If anybody have a tip please ;)

Thanks in advance,

Baptiste

Comment: How about using WebClient object?

Comment: How use it ? I will search on Google but if you have some examples... :)